# Yii : Show Published Post at Top Post List

Tags: php, yii

I used `yii blog from Yii Framework`

I want  Show Only Published Post And Top Liked Post at Top Post List

I used This code at Component

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');
class topPosts extends CPortlet {
public function gettopPosts()
{
    $cirteria=new CDbCriteria();
    $cirteria->select='`post_id`,count(`id`) as `likeCount`';
    $cirteria->condition='status=1';
    $cirteria->group='post_id';
    $cirteria->order='`likeCount` DESC';
    $cirteria->limit=10;
    $result=array();
    $condition = 'status=' . Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED;
    foreach(Like::model()->findAll($cirteria) as $IDS){
        $result[]=Post::model()->findByPk($IDS->post_id, $condition);
    }
    return $result;
}

protected function renderContent()
{
    $this->render('topPosts');
}}
```

but i changed Publish post To Draft POST Show Error 
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I can't quite understand last line of your question. If you could post code before and after change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
foreach(Like::model()->findAll($cirteria) as $IDS){
        $result[]=Post::model()->findByPk($IDS->post_id, $condition);
    }
```

To

```
foreach(Like::model()->findAll($cirteria) as $IDS){
            $post=Post::model()->findByPk($IDS->post_id, $condition);
            if($post instanceof Post)
                $result[] = $post;
        }
```

Its only guessing from my side becouse I dont have enough information like which line couses problem. Nevertheless you always have to check  if you received object or null unless you are 100% sure its object.

Comment: Thank You Arek Your answer Is Correct

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)